# SVN log command line does not show single merged revision ( svn log -r )

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

A huge merge has been done through TortoiseSVN, the subversion version is 1.6

Reading about the way SubVersion (up to version 1.5) manage revision:

> Subversion 1.5 and later keeps a record of merges using properties. This allows us to get a more detailed history of merged changes. For example, if you develop a new feature on a branch and then merge that branch back to trunk, the feature development will show up on the trunk log as a single commit for the merge, even though there may have been 1000 commits during branch development.

Now couple of questions:

If I go in TortoiseSVN history of the branch merged, I can't see the merged revisions, unless I check the "include merged revisions" flag, in this case they are shown in grey, **that's fair enough**!

[image]

The merge message contains some errors:

```
Correcting Shell script that identifies DB objects which have been dropped  from SVN.
Trying to figure out why the shell variable is not getting used properly in
"svn log -qvr..." command
```

and

```
........
(and even) More syntax fixes .. testing call to shell


........
(and even) More syntax fixes .. testing call to shell


........
(and even) More syntax fixes .. testing call to shell

o
```

From Windows instead the message is not shown with the below error:

```
svn: E720008: Write error: Not enough storage is available to process this command.
```

This can be not a major issue, so let's not focus about this..

**Let's focus instead about the command line, when I run the svn log command I'm getting same issues in the commit message:**

I can view all the history (included the merged revision) with the -g parameter, **again fair enough**!

**The MAIN issue is that I can't anymore get the specific merged revision with the SVN LOG -r command**

For example as you can see the revision 69524 shown in grey by TortoiseSVN (with the include merged revisions checked)

***but svn log -r 69524 return a blank message and this happened for all the thousands merged revisions:***

[image]

Is this normal?

Appreciate the way SVN is managing merging now, but is it possible that I can't get anymore the specific merged revision information with svn log -r?

Is this because something went wrong during the merge or is this the normal behavior of new version of subversion?

Honestly it looks really strange for me! Please guys help me understanding, this is killing me!

Thanks

**RESOLVED!**

Running the commands from the branches root fixed the issue, honestly I was expecting the merged revisions to be listed in the release branches cause included into it, even if made in another code lines tree (simulating the different behavior between git squash/rebase/merge+commit)

Comment: Your SVN clients and server are outdated for ehm 6-7 years. Use up to date SVN client and server tools. The current version is SVN 1.9.

Comment: Totally agree and that's what we will do soon, even if it does not depends by me, but in the meanwhile, is this a normal behaviour or something went wrong?

Comment: the "merge message" is the commit log message for merge operation, right? What errors do you see there? When exactly do you receive `E720008: Write error:`?

Comment: Hi Behrep, sorry, that's not really important for me at the moment, it looks like it's a kind of buffer error. What i'ts important to me it's to understand if i can get information about the single merged rev (one of the ones tortoise shows me in grey) with the svn log -r(given-rev) ---> it's not working as you can see, it returns a blank message and i don't understand if that's normal, i mean i can't believe svn give you the possibility to get all the revision, included the merged with the -g parameter, but it does not give you a way to retrieve information about the single merger rev.

Comment: Check my answer. I hope that I understood your case correctly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you should run `svn log --verbose --revision 60524 https://svn.example.com/repos/` or `svn log --verbose --revision 60524 https://svn.example.com/repos/branches` or specify another branch that was actually affected by r60524.

I may misunderstand this issue, but it looks like that you provide incorrect URL. The revision r60524 did not touch `/Release` branch so the command shows nothing. Therefore, I suggest to run the command against the root of your repository and add `--verbose` option. You will see what paths / branches / whatever r60525 affected.

Note that paths in Apache Subversion are **case-sensitive**. Make sure that you enter correct repository URL.